# React-responsive-carousel styles not working

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js, carousel

I am trying to add `react-responsive-carousel` to my `NextJS` project. When i run `npm run dev` everything seems to be fine, however my carousel is rendered with no styles.

```
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
import 'react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css'; // requires loader

const MyCarousel = () => {
   return (
        <Carousel
            autoPlay
            interval={2500}
            showArrows={true}
        >
            <div>content</div>
            <div>content</div>
            <div>content</div>
       </Carousel>
   )
}
```

Documentation says that styles need a loader so I configures `next.config.js` as follows

```
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less');
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withImage = require('next-images');
const theme = require('./app/styles/antdoverrides');

module.exports = withImage(
withCss({
    cssModules: true,
    optimizeFonts: false,
    ...withLess({
        lessLoaderOptions: {
            javascriptEnabled: true,
            importLoaders: 0,
            modifyVars: {
                ...theme,
            },
        },
        cssLoaderOptions: {
            importLoaders: 3,
            localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        },
        webpack5: false,
        webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
            if (isServer) {
                const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style.*?/;
                const origExternals = [...config.externals];
                config.externals = [
                    (context, request, callback) => {
                        if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback();
                        if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
                            origExternals[0](context, request, callback);
                        } else {
                            callback();
                        }
                    },
                    ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
                ];

                config.module.rules.unshift({
                    test: antStyles,
                    use: 'null-loader',
                });
            }
            return config;
        },
    }),
}),


);
```

still not getting desired result. Any hints appreciated

Comment: You do not need to add a loader to load CSS files, Next.js has built-in support for it. However, you should import any global CSS in your custom `_app` instead. See [Built-In CSS Support](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet) for more details.

Answer (score -3):

You need to import your styles in your `_app.js` file if you don't use the objects. Just in your `_app` make import of your styles, something like:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
```

Also you need to `npm run local` or something like this, check your `package.json` file to run locally your project instead of build

Comment: why does he need to npm run local?

Comment: i don't use css, why would i need to import import "../styles/globals.css"; ?